# How to slice a tensor with values along an axis in a numpy-optimized way

Tags: python, numpy

I need to slice a rank-3 tensor selecting a different value of the second dimension for each entry of the first dimension.
I need to do it for each 3-tensor, but for example, consider the following (3,4,3) tensor **A**

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
[ 3  4  5]
[ 6  7  8]
[ 9 10 11]]

[[12 13 14]
[15 16 17]
[18 19 20]
[21 22 23]]

[[24 25 26]
[27 28 29]
[30 31 32]
[33 34 35]]]
```

and the following index list **indices** for the second dimension

```
[1,2,3]
```

then want to obtain the following (3,3) tensor **out**

```
[[ 3  4  5]
[18 19 20]
[33 34 35]]
```

I know how to write it with a for loop:

```
out=[]
for i,ind in enumerate(indices):
    sel.append(A[i,ind,:])
out=np.array(out)
```

But I was wondering if there is a more optimized way of writing such function with only numpy parallel functions and without a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to providing the indices for the second axis you also need to provide the indices for the first axis. You describe your task as follows:

- In row `0` select column `1`
- In row `1` select column `2`
- In row `2` select column `3`

You already have the column indices `[1, 2, 3]`, but you also need to provide the row indices `[0, 1, 2`]:

```py
result = A[np.arange(len(A)), [1,2,3], ...]
```